# GIT Pre-Commit Hook Changes File but Doesn't Add to Commit

Tags: git, bash, github, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I'm using a GIT `pre-commit` hook to locate a string pattern in my README.md file *ex. {{STRING_PATTERN}}* and then changing the string pattern into the desired text/code output, which also contains the current branch name.

Here is the issue. The `pre-commit` script works from the standpoint that it locates the string pattern and replaces it with the correct text/code BUT it doesn't appear to do this prior to committing the changes... meaning that after I run `git commit -m "Updated README.md"` and do a `git status` check the README.md file shows as being modified and if I were to run `git push origin branch_name` the README.md file contains the actual *{{STRING_PATTERN}}* identifier (not wanted) and not the text that it was updated with (which is what I do want).

Here is the `pre-commit` code, as I said, please note that this does work from the standpoint that it locates the string *{{STRING_PATTERN}}* identifier and updates it with the dynamically created text/code – it's just not actually committing those changes, which is the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Echo out text to ensure pre-commit is running
echo "pre-commit working"

# Get the current branch name
function git_branch {
    git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
}

# Set branch variable to current branch
branch=$(git_branch)

# Define the string/pattern marker to search for
# This pattern/string serves as a marker that
# gets replaced with the dynamically created text/code
id="{{STRING_PATTERN}}"

# Dynamically create text/code
# Inject the $branch variable into the correct location of the text
updated_text="Example text containing that is being added to the $branch branch"

# Find the string/pattern and replace it with the text/code
# Then replace it with the build status image
sed -i '' -e "s%{{STRING_PATTERN}}%$updated_text%g" README.md
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do also `git add` in the pre-commit hook to add the changes to the repo.

Comment: when you say add `git add` do you mean that it should be added at the end of the script? So after I run the `sed` code block? Also wouldn't that mean that I would also need to re-run `git commit`?

Comment: Yes, exactly, `git add` at the end of the script